# [Unity]How to rotate the camera automatically without dragging?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am not good in English. I'm sorry.

My question is 
"How can the camera rotate automatically without dragging?"

I implemented it until camera rotation using drag.

But I don't know how to let my camera rotate as the mouse moves.

Comment: What does your code currently look like? Can you show us the part where you rotate the camera using drag?

Comment: Use inputManager.cs to input the drag and pass it on followCamera.cs thank you

Comment: You say you want to rotate automatically without dragging, using the mouse.

So do you mean that you want rotating to always be active according to the mouse movement? Or do you mean that you should be able to activate, and then when activated the rotation moves according to mouse movement?

Comment: That's exactly what I want. and If possible, I would like to have the latter function as well. like camera lock button

Comment: Thank you for expressing what I wanted to say in English.

Comment: You're welcome. I posted an answer I believe will do what you request :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a boolean that checks if the camera rotation is activated, and then have a function that sets that false/true respectively when input is received.

In your inputmanager make the following:

```
public bool isRotating;
void ToggleIfShouldRotate(){
    isRotating = !isRotating;
}
```

!IsRotating will always be the opposite of isRotating.

You also need to decide which key should activate or deactivate the rotation, you can do this with a Keycode variable.

```
[SerializeField]
KeyCode ToggleRotatingKey = KeyCode.Mouse0;
```

I have set it as default to Mouse0, which I believe is the left mouse button. You can change the value in the inspector or in code.

Now use this key in the Update method to toggle the rotation on and off, like this.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(ToggleRotatingKey))
    {
        ToggleIfShouldRotate();
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Now in your rotation script, simply check the boolean value isRotating from the InputManager.